# How to click anywhere on a website to close an option (Selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

here's the link of the website : [website](https://fr.hotels.com/ho410456/?q-check-in=2021-06-24&q-check-out=2021-06-25&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0&sort-order=BEST_SELLER&WOD=4&WOE=5&JHR=1&FPQ=2&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3&YGF=1&modal=dp)

As you can see, there is the option of choose the dates, but I'm not interested in that, I would like to perform some operation on the website but before that I need to close this option. How could I do that ?

here's my script :

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)
 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://fr.hotels.com/ho344560/?q-check-in=2021-06-26&q-check-out=2021-06-27&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0&sort-order=BEST_SELLER&WOD=6&WOE=7&JHR=1&FPQ=2&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3&YGF=1')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").click()
time.sleep(2)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="uolsaJ"]'))).click()

reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@span="k3LKyj"]')
reviews.click()
```

And here's the error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="uolsaJ" aria-label="..." type="button">Acceptez</button> is not clickable at point (217, 701). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_1a95Jj _2w3czg kY8QGj ">...</div>
```

It's like the script doesn't find anything becaus of this option. It kind of obstruct the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with code

1. You are trying to click on the page before even closing the Date selection modal.
2. Your locators are not correct.

Below is the updated code

```py
driver.get(
    'https://fr.hotels.com/ho344560/?q-check-in=2021-06-26&q-check-out=2021-06-27&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0&sort-order=BEST_SELLER&WOD=6&WOE=7&JHR=1&FPQ=2&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3&YGF=1')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body[class='modal-open-menu']").click()
time.sleep(2)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="uolsaJ"]'))).click()

reviews = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[class="k3LKyj"]')
reviews.click()
driver.close()
```

I assume you wanna click on `Guest Review` at last.

Comment: It doesn' open the review however

Comment: `reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="WxdyDo _3ZW5IO"]')
reviews.click()`

Comment: I guess you need to use the correct locator and try again. It should work

Comment: Your locator is working but since you are not performing any further action, you are unable to notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this  and it worked:

The reason is, I am tryin to click on 10, 10 co-ordinates

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://fr.hotels.com/ho344560/?q-check-in=2021-06-26&q-check-out=2021-06-27&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0&sort-order=BEST_SELLER&WOD=6&WOE=7&JHR=1&FPQ=2&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3&YGF=1')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(10 , 10).click().perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="uolsaJ"]'))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main approach is to try to free element to click on so that you close the date screen as when someone is opening this page here is the code that worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep

path = "path to chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
url = "https://fr.hotels.com/ho410456/?q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0&modal=dp"
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(url)
sleep(2)
passDate = driver.find_element_by_class_name("modal-container")
action.click(passDate).perform()
```

i hope this was useful.